# Why use BufferedReader in this case?

Tags: java, xml, bufferedreader

What is the difference between using a BufferedReader around the StringReader in the following code vs using the StringReader only?  By loading up the DOM in line 2 of both examples, it seems like the BufferedReader is not necessary?

```
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(html));
    Document dom = XMLResource.load(is).getDocument();
```

VS

```
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new BufferedReader(new StringReader(html)));
    Document dom = XMLResource.load(is).getDocument();
```

Comment: Using the BufferedReader will actually be marginally slower (and make the code more complicated)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In this particular case, I see no benefit. In general there are two benefits:

- The oh-so-handy [`readLine()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) method is only defined in `BufferedReader` rather than `Reader` (irrelevant here)
- `BufferedReader` reduces IO where individual calls to the underlying reader are potentially expensive (i.e. fewer chunky calls are faster than lots of little ones) - again, irrelevant for `StringReader`

Cut and paste fail?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: My original answer below. The below *isn't* relevant in this case, since the buffered reader is wrapping a StringReader, which wraps a String. So there's no buffering to be performed, and the BufferedReader appears to be redundant. You *could* make an argument for using best/consistent practises, but it would be pretty tenuous.

Possibly the result of a copy/paste, or perhaps an IDE-driven refactor too far!

BufferedReader will attempt to read in a more optimal fashion.

That is, it will read larger chunks of data in one go (in a configurable amount), and then make available as required. This will reduce the number of reads from disk (etc.) at the expense of some memory usage.

To quote from the Javadoc:

> In general, each read request made of
>   a Reader causes a corresponding read
>   request to be made of the underlying
>   character or byte stream. It is
>   therefore advisable to wrap a
>   BufferedReader around any Reader whose
>   read() operations may be costly, such
>   as FileReaders and InputStreamReaders

Comment: And this is relevant to a StringReader how exactly? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The BufferedReader version was copied from some code that used to read from a FileReader?